# What's the best way to check if a Reader is empty?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, is-empty

I need to detect if a `Reader` is empty (will yield no data), before I pass the reader to some external function.

The best I can come up with is to wrap my `Reader` in a `BufferedReader` which guarantees to provide `mark`/`reset` functionality, and then attempt to read a single character before resetting the stream to its original position.

```java
BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(myReader);
if (!isEmpty(buffered)) {
    someOtherFunction(buffered);
}

private boolean isEmpty(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    reader.mark(1);
    int c = reader.read();
    reader.reset();
    return c < 0;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ready()` to check stream is available to read or not [here docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready--)

And also recommended `null` check before checking `ready()`

```
public boolean ready() throws IOException
```

**Tells whether this stream is ready to be read. A buffered character stream is ready if the buffer is not empty, or if the underlying character stream is ready.**

**Note :**

> True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block.